# Setting text indentation inside itemize

Tags: lists, indentation

Inside my LaTeX file I code something like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Item NO 1
\\paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 
paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 
paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 
\item Item NO 2
\\paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 
\item Item NO 3
\\paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 
\end{itemize}
```

The output is like this

- Item NO 1

  paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph
  no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph
  no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1
- Item NO 2

  paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph
  no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph
  no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2
- Item NO 3

  paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph
  no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph
  no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3

But what I want is something like this

- Item NO 1

paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph
no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph
no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1

- Item NO 2

paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph
no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph
no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2

- Item NO 3

paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph
no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraphno3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3

How do I achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to push the item label inward, while fixing the left margin at `0pt`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item NO 1
    \\paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 
    paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 
    paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 
    \item Item NO 2
    \\paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2
    paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2
    paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 
    \item Item NO 3
    \\paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3
    paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3
    paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[itemindent=2em,leftmargin=0pt]
    \item Item NO 1

    paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 
    paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 
    paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 

    \item Item NO 2

    paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2
    paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2
    paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2 paragraph no2

    \item Item NO 3

    paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3
    paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3
    paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 paragraph no3 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Note the empty line after `\item` in the above `itemize` (as opposed to using `\\`).

<sub>For visual clarity, I've added a frame (using [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe)).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This is not the prettiest solution, but it will force it to do what you want:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Item NO 1 \\
\mbox{}\hspace{-10pt}\parbox{\linewidth}{paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 paragraph no1 

\end{itemize}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm)Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.